# Default PHP included with Mac - enable imagecreatefromjpg

Tags: php

I've uncommented gd in php.ini - but I still can't get `imagecreatefromjpg()` to work... How does one enable php with jpg support? (the default php that comes with mac - not xampp or homebrew. trying to avoid multiple installations, low disk space etc)

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpg()

Comment: Which version of macOS - php is not on Modern versions

Comment: It's included with Big Sur and Catalina etc

Comment: I think this is really fun: `$ php --version
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.29-to-be-removed-in-future-macOS (cli) (built: Sep  6 2021 05:14:39) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.29, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Well, that's the thing, lots of Mac legacy software will take time to upgrade so it'd be around for a while? Also, I prefer Big Sur and Catalina for so many compatibility reasons too

Comment: Apple's gone to the trouble to have `php` emit that message of all the scripting languages that macOS includes, so I wouldn't count on it being there.

Comment: So I'm looking for a solution for right now, in Big Sur, where php is still included

Answer (score 1):

I see you have asked not to use homebrew, but if you are doing web development on your Mac then you should really be using it. At a guess, the pre-installed PHP on Mac OS probably does not have the GD library installed.

If you install [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/) you can then run `brew install gd` which will add the GD library which contains `imagecreatefromjpg()` and other image manipulation functions.